# getting commits' tag in git

Tags: git

Gitk has a nice habit of showing me Tags:, Follows: and Precedes: for commit. How do I get the same information from command line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To show the tag of a commit:

```
$ git describe --tags <commit>
```

To show the preceding commit:

```
$ git rev-list -1 <commit>^
```

To show the following commit:

```
$ git rev-list -1 <commit>..HEAD
```

Comment: Follows: and Precedes: actually relate to tags, not commits. So your rev-list examples in fact answer different question. But that is ok, since 'git describe' is just what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: OK -- sorry, I do not use gitk! But I'm glad I still gave something useful

Comment: The solution is `git describe` + `git describe --contains` (as per two answers)

Comment: Also there is `git describe --abbrev=0 <commit>` trick... and `git log --decorate`.

Answer (score 9):

To show the tags that contain a commit (i.e. the tags that the commit precedes):

```
git tag --contains <commit>
```

Comment: You mean tags that succeed a commit? :-) Anyway, this does exactly what I wanted.